# Excel Personal Worksheet VBA Module's won't allow me to view code

Tags: vba, excel

My personal workbook (PERSONAL.xlsm) has stopped allowing me to view the code or any details of the modules I have saved there. It also will not allow me to run any of the Macros it once included. I don't know if they got deleted or are hiding somewhere (but I am hoping it is the later). I have not done anything out of the ordinary. Before this issue was happening all I had done with excel today was run one of these macros (without issue), make an edit to include the solver in a macro, and save it.

In addition to this problem there are a few others that seem to accompany it:

- Occasionally when I close excel without saving a file, excel crashes.
- If I attempt to record a macro (either in the Personal Workbook or to
  another location) one of the following happens:
- a. Excel crashes.
- b. Excel gives me an Invalid Name Error (despite the name being perfectly valid.

It is worth noting that macros not saved in the Personal Workbook work just fine. I am very stumped and cannot find a solution to this problem anywhere. I have tried the obvious (rebooting my computer), the not so obvious (restoring previous versions of files), and the weird (disabling and enabling random things in the excel options section). Please, if you have a solution let me know!

Thank you in advance, all and any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I would uninstall office, make a full-system scan and re-install.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago.  I had to:

- close Excel
- re-name PERSONAL.xlsm to something else *(like temp.xlsm)*
- open Excel and verify it does not "see" or attempt to open PERSONAL
- create a new PERSONAL.xlsm
- copy all VBA from temp.xlsm to the new PERSONAL.xlsm

Comment: But what was the problem? Was there a problem in the System, or Excel it self? Or it was Macro Security problem?

Comment: To start from scratch, if you have problems with any of the steps you try... go to C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\ (replace usrname with your foldername) and rename XLSTART to something else like ARCHIVEXLSTART, when you open a new or your workbook, MS will recreate the XLSTART folder with a blank Workbook.

Answer (score -1):

Can't comment yet, so i apologize in advance.

It is definitely Excel at fault, it happens to me so often (on big files including VBA) that my before_save saves a copy of the file with time in its name, and all module's, userform's, sheet's code as *.frm, *.cls, *.bas.

I usually can also open corrupt files by holding SHIFT key (force designer mode) and then copy manually stuff.